# Get category name being displayed in wordpress outside of loop

Tags: php, wordpress

When I'm displaying a category from the url /category/blah, how do I get the name of that category in my php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`single_cat_title()` should do outside the loop, according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: Suppose it shouldn't be hard to get the slug from there, thanks.